How energy gets distributed equally in body for motion (in collision)
In solids, when two bodies collide—body 'A' moving towards body 'B', which is at rest, and both having the same mass—assuming an elastic collision, body 'A' will transfer all its energy to body 'B'. How does this energy distribute equally throughout body 'B'?
We know that sound waves can pass through body 'B'. So, how does the energy from the collision of body 'A' distribute within body 'B'? Note that sound energy has a specific direction, as does the energy from the collision.
This question arises because, as we study in textbooks, sound energy can pass through any solid. Therefore, in a collision, this energy should also pass through body 'B'. Some argue that these are different scenarios, but there is a commonality between them.
If, through collision, body 'B' can move, then, by the same logic, sound energy should also cause body 'B' to move. If not, how does the energy from the collision distribute equally in body 'B' without passing energy in the same manner as sound energy?
It's logical that sound can pass through, as particles transfer energy to adjacent particles and return to their equilibrium positions. However, when we closely examine how energy distributes in the case of a collision in body 'B', it seems that something is amiss.

This Alpha Phoenix video might help - Are solid objects really “solid”?

ok i will see it but more importantly the second question that is "why sound energy passes through an object but the energy that is given by collision is distributed in object . even if the sound energy is in very small amount but it should be distributed in whole body like in case of energy provided by collision"

The video gets into that.

ya I can see through video, that when he hits the body (that is made up of springs and small ball ) the energy gets distributed and the body is moving like a whole and some how energy is not equally distributed in whole body there is vibrations in body . but it also means that sound energy also acts like this but in our textbooks we have see that sound can pass through solids .  if our textbooks are right and his idea is also right so there is scenario in which both can be right . that is if we considered the sound travels through long distance which can lead to sound pass through it


How does this energy distribute equally throughout body 'B'?

In a perfectly elastic collision, while body A is in contact with body B, both compress such that the initial kinetic energy of A becomes temporarily stored as elastic potential energy in both A and B, much like two springs.
Then as the two bodies separate, the elastic potential of the two bodies then gets converted into the kinetic energy of B as it separates from A, with A stopping.
The following link has an animation of the processes (adjust the animation so there is no damping, as is the case for a perfectly elastic collision). https://www.myphysicslab.com/springs/collide-spring-en.html
Hope this helps.

but you did not have answered the the question why sound energy passes through an object but the energy that is given by collision is distributed in object . even if the sound energy is in very small amount but it should be distributed in whole body like in case of energy provided by collision

@AkshanshBansal No sound energy is produced in a perfectly elastic collision.    If you wish to discuss sound energy edit your post to eliminate the assumption of an elastic collision.

here I am only contexting it that sound can passes through solid but energy that is given by collision gets distributed there are two different cases and I am comparing them that sound can passes through solids as we see in our textbooks but collision that is given by collision gets distributed in whole body
